# Relacionamento 1:N em Java

Tags: java, web-service, hibernate, spring

Tenho uma API e estou criando um relacionamento entre `Cliente` e `AtividadeSecundaria`, onde um cliente possui várias atividades e as atividades pertencem a um cliente, porém, quando faço a consulta pelo *Postman* ele retorna um *erro 500* informando quer não foi possível escrever o JSON. Notei que ele também procura por uma tabela que não existe:

`Table 'teste.cliente_atividade_secundaria' doesn't exist`

mas eu não sei o motivo de estar procurando essa tabela.

Classe **Cliente**:

```
@OneToMany
private List<AtividadeSecundaria> atividadeSecundaria;

public List<AtividadeSecundaria> getAtividadeSecundaria() 
{
    return atividadeSecundaria;
}

public void setAtividadeSecundaria(List<AtividadeSecundaria> atividadeSecundaria) {
    this.atividadeSecundaria = atividadeSecundaria;
}
```

Classe **AtividadeSecundaria**:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_cliente")
private Cliente cliente;
```

Erro no console:

```
SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S022019-08-06 16:22:16.695 ERROR 17748 --- [nio8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'teste.cliente_atividade_secundaria' doesn't exist
2019-08-06 16:22:16.711  WARN 17748 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.teste.agenda.model.Cliente["atividadeSecundaria"])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, deixarei a resposta aqui caso precisem.

Classe **Cliente**:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente")
private List<AtividadeSecundaria> atividadeSecundaria;
```

Classe **AtividadeSecundaria**:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_cliente")
private Cliente cliente;
```

Comment: Marque a sua resposta como correta :)